# Overridable ButtonStyle in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a custom `ButtonStyle` that supplies some defaults but is also overridable.

For instance, on iOS, `DefaultButtonStyle` colors the text blue by default, but you can override that by specifying a `foregroundColor` modifier. Likewise, `PlainButtonStyle` colors the text black by default but is also overridable:

[image: example of overriding foreground color in button styles]

So clearly, it's possible to create a button style that is overridable. However, if I simply create one that sets the foreground color like so, it is not overridable:

```swift
public struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    public func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View
    {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

[image: example of not being able to override foreground color in custom button style]

How can I make a `ButtonStyle` that supplies a default foreground color but is also overridable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems to not be possible yet. Check out this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69016509

Answer (score 2):

You can implement it like this:

```
public struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

    let color: Color

    public init(color: Color = .accentColor) {
        self.color = color
    }

    public func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(color)
    }
}
```